# What is the probability of choosing 5 random students whose (individual) grade is higher than 1149 points?

Tags: probability

The number of students whose grade is higher than 1149 is 44, and the total of students is 135. If the question where only for 1 random student, it would be 32%, but I don't know how it is for more than that.

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE. Can you show what you've tried on this?

Answer (score 2):

Number of ways of choosing $5$ students = $135 \choose 5$

Number of ways of choosing $5$ high-scoring students = $44 \choose 5$

Can you see where to go from here?

Comment: @JFRN It would be helpful, if you would check the answer.$\color{blue}{\checkmark}$